# Logic to get only one row in result set

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

am stuck at point to build the logic. Can anyone help me ?

requirement:

For privacyType = 'Primary Address'  if there is >1 row where SI0_ADDR.ADDR_TYPE_CODE = 'M', display the row where currentDate() is between SI0_ADDR.ADDR_EFF_DATE and SI0_ADDR.ADDR_EXPR_DATE.

my query is :

```
select STU_ID
      ,case when Privacyflag = '' then 'N'
            else Privacyflag
        end Privacyflag
      ,type from (
select a.STU_ID,Privacyflag,a.type 
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ADDR_EXPR_DATE DESC) disp_nm  from (
select ad.STU_ID, case when ad.ADDR_TYPE_CODE = 'M' then ad.ADDR_PRIVACY_FLAG
                       when ad.ADDR_TYPE_CODE=''  then 'N'
                  end Privacyflag, 'Primary Phone' type
                , case when ADDR_EXPR_DATE = '1900-01-01' then '2100-12-31'
                       else ADDR_EXPR_DATE
                 end as ADDR_EXPR_DATE

from SI0_ADDR ad
where ad.STU_ID = @studentid ) a
where Privacyflag is not null
) ab
where ab.disp_nm = '1'
```

This logic is not working in some of the cases

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  "not working in some of the cases" is not a problem description.

Comment: where is 'Primary Address' in your query? I don't see where you have used it

Answer (score 0):

You're not qualifying by the date in any way, which was part of your requirements.  Your query doesn't need so many nested sub-queries.  The `PrivacyFlag` doesn't seem to be part of your question, so I didn't work it into this example.  And your example shows `Primary Phone`, but your question talks about `Primary Address`, so I'm not sure how to work that out.

In any case, here is a very simple example that shows the data, and how to pull the *one* record with the latest expiration date, and also the latest effective date (in case there are two records with the same expiration date).

```
create table #temp (stu_id int, type varchar(10), address varchar(50), eff_date datetime, expr_date datetime)

insert into #temp values
(1, 'primary', '123 NW 52nd', '1/1/2016', '1/1/1900'),
(1, 'primary', '942 SE 33rd', '1/2/2016', '12/31/2016'),
(1, 'primary', '721 SW 22nd', '4/1/2015', '1/1/1900')

select top 1 *
from   (
         select stu_id
               ,type
               ,address
               ,eff_date
               ,case when expr_date = '1/1/1900' then '12/31/2100' else expr_date end as expr_date
         from   #temp
         where  stu_id = 1
           and  type = 'primary'
       ) as a
where  getdate() between eff_date and expr_date
order by a.expr_date desc, a.eff_date desc

drop table #temp
```

You could even do it with zero sub-queries, but then you'd need to duplicate the `case` statement into the `where` and `order by` parts of the query:

```
select top 1
       stu_id
      ,type
      ,address
      ,eff_date
      ,case when expr_date = '1/1/1900' then '12/31/2100' else expr_date end as expr_date
from   #temp
where  stu_id = 1
  and  type = 'primary'
  and  getdate() between eff_date and case when expr_date = '1/1/1900' then '12/31/2100' else expr_date end
order by case when expr_date = '1/1/1900' then '12/31/2100' else expr_date end desc
      ,eff_date desc
```

With such a small dataset, the `showplan` didn't indicate which query would be most efficient; it showed the same identical query plan for both queries, except the first `select` statement took 7 CPU cycles to compile the plan and the second `select` statement took 2 CPU cycles to compile the plan.  You may want to test against a larger dataset on real tables with indexes, etc., and see which performs the best.